# Django Rest Framework Documentation nested Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, documentation, serialization

I am using django rest framework documentation module to document my API.
I am facing a problem in the sense that nested serializers do not appear in my documentation, but only the outermost does.
As an example I have the following code:

```
    class MyFirstSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        some_data = serializers.CharField(help_text="a number")
        more_data = serializers.CharField(help_text="a letter")

    class MySecondSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        email = serializers.EmailField(help_text="the email address")
        number = serializers.CharField(help_text="a number")
        another_serializer = MyFirstSerializer(help_text='a JSON structure')
```

The way the program works, is by having a nested JSON structure. However the documentation modules on mentions the fact that `another_serializer` is a field, and does not show what kind of data is supposed to be passed, somethinng like:

```
    POST your/endpoint/
    Parameter           Description
    email               the email address
    number              a number
    another_serializer  a JSON structure
```

I would like a way for the documentation to be done recursively on all my field, in order to have a complete description of my endpoints, something like:

```
    POST your/endpoint/
    Parameter           Description
    email               the email address
    number              a number
    another_serializer  
         some_data      a number
         more_data      a letter
```

Comment: which api used for documentation coreapi ?

Comment: @a_k_v, yes indeed

Comment: Then its the problem with coreapi. It not support nested serializer. https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/398

Comment: You can solve it by using custom definition for coreapi or using metadata, i guess. I am not sure about it.